# Champions with ultimate that are not priority?

Tags: league-of-legends

Except Udyr, are there champions whose R isn't a priority to be acquired at level 6 or level up at 11?

Comment: Possibly the ones who have transformations, such as Udyr. Sometimes Jayce. It's all about personal preference.

Comment: Current (old) AP sion's ult as well. But ap sion is going to be obsolete very soon

Comment: It's always fun to play Udyr and say "guys, I'm lvl 6. I have my ult now"... or "You only say that because you have a REAL ultimate"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually The ultimate of a champion is intended to be his strongest skill that's unlocked at level 6, therefor I wouldn't consider Udyrs R as an ultimate but rather a default skill. Also Nidalee, Jayce, Karma and Elise don't have real ultimates. But those are definitely the champions where you can delay leveling it.

**Please note that delaying or ignoring an ultimate is extremely situational and in 95% of the cases it's a lot better to just level up your ultimate instead of another skill**. Also In order to delay an ultimate, your second priority spell must show a good increase of damage/scaling/cooldownreduction so keep that in mind (or your ult has to be useless which doesn't happen too often now).

Anyways I'm gonna list some champions where you can ignore or delay your ultimate **situationally**.

- **Fiddlesticks**: You can delay your ultimate when playing **mid** (especially if you're getting pushed), since it's often better to have some extra fear/damage and usually your ult isn't too strong when playing middle. If you plan to roam, teamfight or if you are against a champion with no gapclosers it's still better to pick it up at lvl 6.
- **Gnar**: You can delay your ultimate for an extra point in W if you see that your opponent doesn't let you smash him into a wall and if there are very few jungle fights going on.
- **Irelia**: Very situational but you can pick up a point in E where a longer stun saves your life or wins a fight.
- **Sion**: When playing AP Sion your ultimate is rather Useless. The only reason to pick it up is for extra sustain if you're getting harassed a lot. Note however that this will change with the rework.
- **Pantheon**: As Marco pointed out in his [comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185590/champions-with-ultimate-that-are-not-priority#comment251681_185607), Pantheon is also a champion where you can delay your ultimate if you don't plan on ganking other lanes (if you play top or mid). An extra point in E will provide an incredible boost to your damage when duelling other champions.

Now these would be all the champions where you could take it into consideration (and of course Jayce, Nida, Karma, Elise) but usually **it's better to skill the ultimate** so keep that in mind if you plan on skipping the ult. Always think about what will be more useful if you get ganked for example and think about the matchup.

Comment: Pantheon also comes to mind while still in laning phase. You might consider Shen, although the global assists are probably nice to have.

Comment: Hmmm...I never considered doing this on champions whose ultimates aren't transformations. I might have to try this out now ;)

Comment: @Shelby115 Well you can try it but as I said: **Be careful**! It's super situational.

Comment: I do not even think that this is situational. On all the champions you named it does not make sense to delay the ultimate except Sion. 

Fiddlesticks mid - Why would you play him mid if you do not want to roam and get kills. Just play something else
Gnar - Point in W gives you tiny bit more dmg and ms, ult hepls you against gans very well no point in delaying it
Irelia - Sustain in ganks and fast wavepush, again no point
Pantheon - Same with Fiddle. Do not pick Panth if you do not intent to use ult to roam.

Comment: @Deutro Well, there are some cases where you can't roam. What if your enemy is just constantly pushing turret? If played right (i.e. Enemy tower hugs and when you leave enemy mid laner starts pushing immediately) you could end up losing tower for nothing. (Given there's almost always something you can do it's not always obvious). So if you were being forced to stay in lane, it might be a better idea to get another point in another skill instead of your ultimate. It's a very very extreme case, but I could see it.

Comment: If you get pushed to your tower constantly you do something wrong as Pantheon or Fiddlesticks. Pantheon is a strong laner early on and Middlesticks has good wave clear since he will have several points in his e. If you plan on losing lane (if you are pushed onto your tower all game long you lose the lane because you have 0 pressure and your ult does nothing in lane) why would you pick these champions in the first place.

Even if you lose lane and have Fiddle / Panth, the enemy jungler might invade and you can respont way easier with your ults.

Comment: Never a good idea to avoid leveling up Irelia's ult though.

Comment: @Fabián Yeah well I usually wait with skilling ult/E until the next usage comes up, I then quickly decide what to skill. There are a few situations where a point in E is better than the ult.

Answer (score 1):

Another example is Jayce. But with him it is the same as with Elise and Nidalee. A boost in some defensive stats.
The difference between these 4 champions and Udyr is that they get their "ultimate" at level one where as Udyr does not have an "ultimate". He just has 4 spells he can freely choose. Thus I would say Udyr is the only champion who can get away with not leveling his "ultimate".

Answer (score 0):

I would say these three, going on a very thin argument that they aren't exactly *essential*:

- Elise
- Nidalee
- Karma

All they really do is boost your stats, which yes, could be argued that it's not a *priority*, but it's too beneficial not to have it.

Answer (score 0):

After putting one point into Tryndamere's ult, some players avoid putting more points into it, since the difference is very minor.

The only benefit is the cooldown (-10 seconds) and the fury gain upon activation (+25). The duration remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

If your ult has a ridiculously long cd, and you've just hit level 11, I'd delay putting a point in it so long as you're ahead as by the time it's of cd you will have probably levelled up again. (note that this is only when you are massively ahead and levelling is a guarantee.